# Como passar parâmetros para o resource controller direto da View com o Helper url()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Tenho a seguinte rota na minha aplicação Laravel (v5.5):

```
Route::resource('tags', 'Painel\TagsController');
```

Conforme [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#restful-naming-resource-route-parameters) oficial, isso me dá uma rota com action edit, verbo GET e URI (/photos/{photo}/edit). Na minha View preciso preciso gerar uma lista, exemplo:

```
<a title="Editar" href="{{ url('/painel/tags/1/edit') }}">
<a title="Editar" href="{{ url('/painel/tags/2/edit') }}">
<a title="Editar" href="{{ url('/painel/tags/3/edit') }}">
```

Os valores numéricos representam os registros retornados do banco e impressos via laço de repetição. Consigo fazer o que quero desta forma:

```
<a title="Editar" href="{{ url('/painel/tags/' . $t->id . '/edit') }}">
```

Porém, queria ver se algum Helper do Laravel permite fazer isso de forma mas elegante, algo como:

```
<a title="Editar" href="{{ url('/painel/tags/edit', $t->id) }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Tem outras duas formas que você pode fazer isso:

[Url a partir de uma rota nomeada](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/urls#urls-for-named-routes) (o *resource* já faz isso também pra gente)

```
echo route('tags.edit', ['id' => 1]);

// http://example.com/painel/tags/1
```

[Url a partir da *action* daquele *controller*](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/urls#urls-for-controller-actions)

```
action('Painel\TagsController@edit', ['id' => 1]);

// http://example.com/painel/tags/1
```

Com isso o Laravel se encarrega de resolver a rota para você, caso esteja usando algum `Route::group` e afins.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer isso usando `route()` no lugar de `url()`, porém em `route()` você utiliza o nome da rota e  não o caminho... Como você usou o metodo `Route::resource()` esses nomes foram dados automaticamente, para ver o nome de uma derminada rota que você deseja usar você pode utilizar o comando `php artisan route:list` ele retornará uma lista com todas as rotas e suas informações.

No seu caso como é um GET para Edit, provavelmente o nome será `'tags.edit'` então você pode chamar a rota assim: `route('tags.edit', $t->id)`